# Iterating over a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
  County Date  Cases 
0 Adams 1/20/20 0
1 Adams 1/21/20 550
2 Adams 1/22/20 650
3 Adams 1/23/20 800
4 Adams 1/24/20 900
5 Adams 1/25/20 1000
```

I wanted to create a new column 'Cases per day' and I want to fill it with the difference between index 1 and index 0, index 3 and index 2...etc until the whole column is field. Any idea on how I could go about this. Ideally I want the new output to look like this

```
  County Date    Cases  Cases Per Day
0 Adams  1/20/20 0      0
1 Adams  1/21/20 550    550
2 Adams  1/22/20 650    100
3 Adams  1/23/20 800    150 
4 Adams  1/24/20 900    100
5 Adams  1/25/20 1000   100
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page. `Any idea on how I could go about this` - Start with the getting started section of the Pandas docs then move on to the user guide section - practice the examples in those - eventually you will get ideas on how to solve your problem - try them out, if you run into obstacles come back and ask specific questions.

Comment: [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid to iterate over pandas DataFrames or Series and try instead to use the vectorized methods of pandas or numpy. Here, `shift` will help:

```
df['Cases Per Day'] = df['Cases'] - df['Cases'].shift().fillna(0).astype('int')
```

will give the expected result with no (explicit) loop.